# Factorial calculator presenting a negative number that should be positive. How to Fix?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to code a factorial calculator that goes as high as `20!` 
I get to `19` and it's fine, but when I try to calculate `20!` it returns a negative number.
How can I fix this?

Now, a bit of background (in case what I have is completely incorrect) I did not take the VB.Net class (where they learned factorials) so I have legit NO CLUE what I'm doing here.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int f = 1, n, i;
        n = Int32.Parse(txtNumber.Text);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            f = f * i;
            txtFactorial.Text = f.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Expected: `20! = 2,432,902,008,176,640,000`
Actual: `20! = -2102132736`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue);` Try with `long`/`ulong`.

Comment: That number does not fit into [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) (max 2147483647). Use [`long`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) (max 9223372036854775807) instead. You get a negative number because there is an overflow happening here.

Comment: BTW: You should always check if the used datatypes can hold the expected values. And also, you shouldn't do this in the click handler ... but that's another story.

Comment: I just saw since "20" is only an example, you should follow the answer and use BigInteger, not long as suggested in my comment above. I'd also like to add that this will throw an exception and make your program crash if the users enters an invalid input. Never trust user input.

Comment: Also don't set the value of the textbox in the loop. You will only see the last value anyways, so it's unnecessary calculation for your program.

Comment: Another word about requirements: If your requirement is to support up to 20! (but not more) you should definitely validate users' input to meet that requirement.

Answer (score 3):

For large numbers you can use [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2) struct.

Answer (score 1):

The type *int* is too small when you're dealing with this big numbers.

With the type int you can represent a maximum value of 2,147,483,647, but you want to store a more than 1B times bigger number (this is why it overflows and you get an incorrect negative number - [read integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)).

You'll need the type **long** for this calculation. It's enough for 20!, but if you work with even bigger numbers then use BigInteger.

> I get to 19 and it's fine

You should check that value again. Returning a positive number doesn't mean it's correct. I'm pretty sure with int you get an incorrect value at 19! too.

Comment: While `long` will be ok for the example "20!" , it will probably be not for bigger numbers. So she should either have a max value that the user is allowed to enter, so the result will fit into long or use BigInteger.

Comment: @Fildor It's not an example, it's her requirement.

Comment: That's what she said, yes. But _the code_ does not. Any parseable int is allowed. So user could as well enter 687687! ... Either she supports that or validates input. But that's beyond the question, I'll admit.

Comment: By the way, supporting more than "20" also meets the requirement. So for me, this would be kind of a grey area, what to do. I'd probably have a talk with the Product Owner about what he wants exactly. But I think this is more of an academic environment. So just going with BigInt would be the safest while still easy solution.